# Error: Merge two sorted linkedlist using dummy head technique in Python

Tags: python, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to solve merge two sorted linkedlist problem using dummy head technique. For some reason I have an error coming from passing an argument to my dummy head holder. The output suppose to merge both linkedlist like this: 1-> 1-> 2-> 3-> 7-> None

I would be happy if you please guide which data needs to pass in my dummy head variable? Thanks in advance! This is the error I have:

```
    dummy = LinkedList()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data
```

Here's my complete code:

```py
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


def print_list(head: LinkedList) -> None:
    while head:
        print(head.data, end=" -> ")
        head = head.next
    print("None")


def merge_lists(headA, headB):
    dummy = LinkedList()
    curr = dummy

    while headA != None and headB != None:
        if headA.data < headB.data:
            curr.next = headA
            headA = headA.next
        else:
            curr.next = headB
            headB = headB.next

        curr = curr.next

    if headA != None:
        curr.next = headA
    else:
        curr.next = headB

    return dummy.next



node1 = LinkedList(1)
node1.next = LinkedList(2)
node1.next.next = LinkedList(7)


node2 = LinkedList(1)
node2.next = LinkedList(3)

print(merge_lists(node1, node2)) # 1-> 1-> 2-> 3-> 7-> None
```

Comment: You are creating an object which needs a parameter: ```dummy = LinkedList()```

Comment: Correct, I tried to pass None, "dummy" as a parameter but I still don't see the output. When I passed None as a parameter for example, it shows me a reference like this: <__main__.LinkedList object at 0x7f8142cb5df0>

Comment: You are returning an object that is why the output looks like this. You may want another function which will iterate over the list and print the data of each node

Comment: I used print_list function instead of just print, that solved that issue. I tried your way of creating another function like this : for i in range(headA + headB):
        print(dummy(i), end = " ") right after the final return, It didn't work. Could you please guide me how to do this .Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a dummy node, and you never ever *use* the data attribute of that node, you can pass anything as argument, like `None`:

```
dummy = LinkedList(None)
```

Alternatively, you could specify that providing an argument is optional, and define the constructor as follows:

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
```

Unrelated, but at the end of your script you have:

```
print(merge_lists(node1, node2))
```

This will print the object reference. You probably wanted to call the function you have defined for this purpose:

```
print_list(merge_lists(node1, node2))
```

If you want `print` to work like that, then instead of the `print_list` function, enrich `LinkedList` with an `__iter__` method to ease iteration over the values in the list, and a `__repr__` or `__str__` method as follows:

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

    def __iter__(self):
        head = self
        while head:
            yield head.data
            head = head.next
        yield None  # Optional

    def __repr__(self):
        return " -> ".join(map(str, self))
```

...and then you can do

```
print(merge_lists(node1, node2))
```

Comment: Yeah, I did that before I post my code here. After the above changes, I still don't see the output of: 1-> 1-> 2-> 3-> 7-> None. Instead it shows me: <__main__.LinkedList object at 0x7f8142cb5df0> which is somehow a reference. Did you know any other way that can show my output. Thanks anyway!

Comment: That's because you don't use the `print_list` function. Use that instead of `print`.

Comment: That worked well. Thank you so much. Someone else mentioned creating another function that prints the list of each node without using print_list function. Any idea of that please, thanks once again?

Comment: *"Someone else mentioned creating another function"*: there are thousands of ways to create another function that prints. Not sure what you mean.

Comment: You are a legend. Thanks for showing me different ways to print my output. One last question please before we close this question: TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
    print(merge_lists(headA, headB)). It prints the output but I gives me data type error aswell. Do I have use string data type for this solution or I can also use integers, how do I get ride of this error? Thanks!

Comment: Did an update to that last part, to map to string, and making the list iterable.

Comment: Thank you so much Trincot, I now understood and also I need to look up those methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
        
class linkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        
    def insertNode(self, data):
        newnode = node(data)
        
        if self.head is None:
            self.head =  newnode
        else:
            current = self.head
            while current.next is not None:
                current = current.next
            current.next = newnode
    def printLL(self):
        
        current = self.head
        while current.next is not None:
            print(current.data, end='----->')
            current = current.next
        print(current.data, '------>None')
    def sortLL(self):
        arr=[]
        current = self.head
        while current.next is not None:
            arr.append(current.data)
            current = current.next
        arr.append(current.data)
        arr.sort()
        self.head = None
        
        for i in arr:
            self.insertNode(i)
            
def mergeTwoSortedLL(l, l2):
    
    current1 = l.head
    current2 = l2.head
    l3 = linkedList()
    
    while current1 is not None and current2 is not None:
        
        if current1.data < current2.data:
            l3.insertNode(current1.data)
            current1 = current1.next
        else:
            l3.insertNode(current2.data)
            current2 = current2.next
            
    if current1 is None:
        
        while current2.next is not None:
            l3.insertNode(current2.data)
            current2 = current2.next
        l3.insertNode(current2.data)
    else:
        while current1.next is not None:
            l3.insertNode(current1.data)
            current1 = current1.next
        l3.insertNode(current1.data)
        
    return l3

        
        
    
    
                 
                           
    
    
    
            
l = linkedList()
l.insertNode(9)
l.insertNode(18)
l.insertNode(11)
l.insertNode(15)
l.insertNode(1)
l.insertNode(8)
l.sortLL()
l.printLL()
l2 = linkedList()
l2.insertNode(9)
l2.insertNode(18)
l2.insertNode(11)
l2.insertNode(15)
l2.insertNode(1)
l2.insertNode(8)
l2.sortLL()
l2.printLL()
mergeTwoSortedLL(l,l2).printLL()
```